# Isn't weak interactions necessarily violate strangeness?

Tags: particle-physics, conservation-laws, standard-model, weak-interaction

The electron-proton elastic scattering process $$e^-+p^+\to e^-+p^+$$ can take place either via a photon exchange (electromagnetic interaction) or via $Z^0$ exchange (weak interaction). But isn't weak interactions necessarily violate strangeness? But this process conserves strangeness. What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you think weak interactions necessarily violate strangeness? Just asserting something that you already know to be false gives answerers no hint as to what they need to explain to you to clear up the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, weak interactions do not necessarily change strangeness.
There are many weak interactions where strangeness is conserved.
For example $\beta$ decay (mediated by $W$ boson)
$$n \to p^+ + e^- + \bar{\nu}_e$$
and many others. See [Weak interaction - Interaction types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_interaction#Interaction_types).